# ADF slice based scheduling and lagged data

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a data source with a timeline data that partitioned by ExportDate not by EventDate. So a partition can contain a data that have:

1. EventTime = ExportDate (99%)
2. EventTime < ExportDate (~ 1%)

We would like to have an ability to automatically rerun data slices for past N days (as a sliding window). For example, let current date is 03-15-2017, so today we should reprocess data slices:

```
current date
03-15-2017

past N days
03-14-2017
03-13-2017
...
03-(15-N)-2017
```

But looks like ADF dont provide any options in **scheduler** or **policy** nodes. So my question is how to implement it with ADF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you have 2 options here...

**1)** Create a custom activity in ADF to ingest data for the sliding window you describe. You can pass parameters to the custom activity and get it to import a range of files. This would of course be written in C# so you could pretty much do anything you need here.

This is currently the best approach I can think of and will give you the more dynamic flexibility you require.

**2)** Use the PowerShell cmdlets to override the status of a set of time slices for a given slides period.

For example:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName `
    -DatasetName "YourDataSetName" `
    -StartDateTime 2017-03-01 ` #start, pass as param to be dynamic
    -EndDateTime 2017-03-15 `   #end, pass as param to be dynamic
    -Status "Waiting" ` #Waiting to rerun
    -UpdateType "Individual"
```

You could then trigger this with Azure Automation. Not ideal but would solve the issue for now until more comprehensive scheduling is available in ADF.

I appreciate that neither options are ideal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. i had the same ideas before i wrote the post. gonna try to implement it.